# Convert ASP.NET MVC web application from http to https

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC web application in http I want to convert it to https. I have change in code from http to https but after deployed on internet I had some javascript library errors , example :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://MySite/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

What is solution?

Comment: The solution is to reference the https version of this dependency in your script tags instead of the http version - e.g. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js

Comment: Just reference the https version instead of the http version - [How to fix a site with mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

Answer (score 4):

When `HTTPS` is enabled, all your assets have to be requested over `HTTPS` as well, otherwise you get mixed-content warnings as both secured and unsecured elements are being served up on a page that should be completely encrypted. Switch to `HTTPS`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use protocol-relative URLs, i.e. instead of:

```
<!-- this.. -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- ..or this -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

You can instead use:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Using the protocol-relative syntax, the resource will load in `HTTP` when requested from a non-secure page, and `HTTPS` when requested from a secure one.

The downfall to this is that using protocol-relative schemes on *non-secure pages* will retrieve cross-origin assets in a non-secure fashion. This means that you could be missing out on benefits that `HTTPS` provides when requesting (for example) resources from a CDN, such as receiving the assets over [`HTTP/2`](https://http2.github.io/)*. As you're going full `HTTPS` this is not an actual concern, so use it at your own discretion.

<sub>*`HTTP/2` does not require the use of encryption (e.g. TLS), but some implementations have stated that they will only support `HTTP/2` when it is used over an encrypted connection, and currently no browser supports `HTTP/2` unencrypted. ([HTTP/2 FAQ](https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When you have an `https` site you should load all your JavaScript content (if they're external links) through `https`

reference:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js
```

instead of:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js
```

The answer is as simple as that!

Comment: if you go to it on the browser it loads fine.. which means it is loading the JavaScript.